# Annotating tables

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tabularx, highlighting

I'm trying to annotate a table by highlighting and annotating the final column, yet once I use the`\tabnode` together with coloring I get misalignment. Either the content of the cell marked with `\tabnode` is misplaced outside of the table, or the cell is stretched in width (whereas all cells should be equal width). What is the right way to fix this? Here's a sample code I'm using:

```
   \documentclass{beamer}
   \usepackage[beamer,customcolors]{hf-tikz}
   \usepackage{tabularx}
   \begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{Title}
    \newcounter{nodecount}
    \newcommand\tabnode[1]{\addtocounter{nodecount}{1}\tikz\node(\arabic{nodecount}){#1};}

     \tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture,baseline]
     \tikzstyle{every node}+=[inner sep=0pt,anchor=base,
     minimum width=1.8cm,align=center,text depth=.25ex,outer sep=1.5pt]
     \tikzstyle{every path}+=[thick, rounded corners]


   \newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{red}}c}
   \begin{table}[ht]
     \centering
     \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|g|}\hline
      bla   &  bla  & bla   & \tabnode{$b_1$}& \hline
  bla   &  bla  & bla   & bla            & \hline       
  bla   &  bla  & bla   & bla            & \hline   
  bla   &  bla  & bla   & bla            & \hline
  bla   &  bla  & bla   & bla            & \hline       
  bla   &  bla  & bla   & bla            & \hline
     \end{tabular}
   \end{table}


   \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]

    \node [right=2cm,above=2cm,minimum width=0pt] at (1) (A) {A};
    \draw [<-,out=5,in=180] (1) to (A);

   \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{frame}
```

Comment: I'm very happy if you find useful `hf-tikz`, however, in this MWE it is not used at all (either for highlighting the column or to mark the position for the annotation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has some mistakes that will produce errors (in particular, you declared four columns but were using five and you forgot the line changing commands): below I corrected them and fixed other aspects:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[beamer,customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\newcounter{nodecount}
\newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{red}}c}

\newcommand\tabnode[1]{%
  \addtocounter{nodecount}{1}%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[inner sep=0pt] (\thenodecount) {#1};}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}

\tikzset{
every picture/.style={remember picture,baseline},
every node/.style={
  inner sep=0pt,
  anchor=base,
 minimum width=1.8cm,
 align=center,
 text depth=.25ex,
 outer sep=1.5pt},
every path/.style={
  thick, 
  rounded corners
  }
}  

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|g|c|}
 \hline
  bla   &  bla  & bla   & \tabnode{$b_1$} \\ \hline
  bla   &  bla  & bla   & bla \\\hline   
  bla   &  bla  & bla   & bla \\\hline   
  bla   &  bla  & bla   & bla \\\hline
  bla   &  bla  & bla   & bla \\\hline   
  bla   &  bla  & bla   & bla \\\hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node [right=2cm,above=2cm,minimum width=0pt] at (1) (A) {A};
  \draw [<-,out=5,in=180] (1) to (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd like to propose you, however, another approach using the `tikzmark` library: the general idea is still the same; using \tikzmark you place a "mark", as in `\tikzmark{a}` and then you can use this mark using `pic cs`. as in `\draw (pic cs:a) -- ++(1,0);`. A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[beamer,customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{red}}c}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}

\tikzset{
every picture/.style={remember picture,baseline},
every node/.style={
  inner sep=0pt,
  anchor=base,
 minimum width=1.8cm,
 align=center,
 text depth=.25ex,
 outer sep=1.5pt},
every path/.style={
  thick, 
  rounded corners
  }
}  

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|g|c|}
 \hline
  bla   &  bla  & bla   & $b_1$\tikzmark{a} \\ \hline
  bla   &  bla  & bla   & bla \\\hline   
  bla   &  bla  & bla   & bla \\\hline   
  bla   &  bla  & bla   & bla \\\hline
  bla   &  bla  & bla   & bla \\\hline   
  bla   &  bla  & bla   & bla \\\hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node [right=2cm,above=2cm,minimum width=0pt] at (pic cs:a) (A) {A};
  \draw [<-,out=5,in=180] ([xshift=15pt]{pic cs:a}) to (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It's not clear why are you loading the `hf-tikz` package, since it doesn't pay any rol in your MWE.